# Haxe Starling Object Pooling with Dynamic Object Type

Tags: html, haxe, starling-framework, openfl

I am very new to haxe openfl, I used to develop game with flash and starling , I am confused about the conversion from flash to openfl haxe.

```
public class StarlingPool
{
public var items:Array;
private var counter:int;

    public function StarlingPool(type:Class, len:int)
    {
        items = new Array();
        counter = len;

        var i:int = len;
        while(--i > -1)
            items[i] = new type();
    }

    public function getSprite():DisplayObject
    {
        if(counter > 0)
            return items[--counter];
        else
            throw new Error("You exhausted the pool!");
    }

    public function returnSprite(s:DisplayObject):void
    {
        items[counter++] = s;
    }

    public function destroy():void
    {
        items = null;
    }
}
```

Here is a Starling Pool Class created by Lee Brimelow I was wondering how can I convert it to Haxe,

I tried like -

```
 class StarlingPool
{
    public var items:Array<Class>;
    private var counter:Int;

    public function new(type:Class<Dynamic>, len:Int)
    {
        items = new Array<Class<Dynamic>>();
        counter = len;

        var i:Int = len;
        while (--i > -1)
            items[i] = type;
    }

    public function getSprite():Class<Dynamic>
    {
        if (counter > 0)
            return items[--counter];
        else
            throw new Error("You exhausted the pool!");
            return null;
    }

    public function returnSprite(s:Dynamic):Void
    {
        items[counter++] = s;
    }

    public function destroy():Void
    {
        items = null;
    }
}
```

But I dose not work ,maybe I am not casting it properly ?,
for example -

```
pool = new StarlingPool(Bullet, 100);
var b:Bullet = cast(pool.getSprite()); //or 
var b:Bullet = cast(pool.getSprite(),Bullet)
```

Comment: You defined items as `Array<Class>` and then redefine it as `Array<Class<Dynamic>>`?

That's rather nonsensical to me.

Comment: Even if you didn't do that, you're literally returning a `Class` object to something that's being casted to an instance of that `Class`. Somewhere in your pool class you need to instantiate that object, likely through the `Type` stdlib.

Comment: Notice the line in the original code that says `items[i] = new type()`. That's actually instantiating an object of that class. You aren't.

Comment: Sorry that was just an rough example , I did that because I actually don't know how can I do `new type()` in haxe. Haxe dose not suppose this kind of syntax.

Comment: Yeah that may have sounded more negative than I meant it too. Take a look at the `Type` class in std lib, it should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Better not to use Dynamic, especially if you could create [typed object pool](https://coderwall.com/p/efo8xq/haxe-objectpooling)
More information about [Type Parameters](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameters.html)

Comment: Ok this is what I was looking for but right now the code seems to work like , `var pool:StarlingPool<myClass>;   pool = new StarlingPool(myClass,15);` now I have to specify my class type 2 times right ? can't I do it once ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do to make it work the Haxe way:

- make a StarlingPool with type parameters. Then it is generic, so also lets change the function names to `getItem` and `putItem`.
- `len` and `items` are read-only (default get access, no set access).
- Don't use an array of Class but provide an allocator-function that returns an *instance*. This can be nice, because you can prepare/decorate the new Sprite outside of the pool class. Which can be handy when having different pools.
- Instead of throwing errors when pool is empty, I would just return new instances using the allocator-function. That makes more sense for me. Of course you have to *measure* a decent length for the pool to make good balance of memory usage, so you could log a warning there for debugging purposes.

Here is the StarlingPool class:

```
class StarlingPool<T>
{
    public var items(default, null):Array<T>;
    public var len(default, null):Int;

    private var _allocator:Void->T;

    public function new(len:Int, allocator:Void->T)
    {
        this.len = len;
        _allocator = allocator;

        // create array full of instances using comprehension syntax
        items = [for(i in 0...len) allocator()];
    }

    public function getItem():T
    {
        if (items.length > 0)
            return items.pop();
        else
            // instead of returning null, why not just provide new objects.
            return _allocator();
    }

    public function putItem(item:T):Void
    {
        if(items.length < len)
        {
            items.push(item);
        }
    }

    public function destroy():Void
    {
        _allocator = null;
        items = null;
    }
}
```

Now thats a nice pool, You can use it like this:

```
var pool = new StarlingPool(50, function() return new Sprite());

trace(pool.items.length); // actual items in pool: 50
var item = pool.getItem();
trace(pool.items.length); // actual items in pool: 49
pool.putItem(item); // give item back
trace(pool.items.length); // actual items in pool: 50

$type(item); // type of this item is: Sprite
```

Since the pool is generic you can create a different object pool with other objects in it. (You can't mix multiple types, of course)

```
var pool2 = new StarlingPool(50, function() return new OtherObject());

var item2 = pool2.getItem();
$type(item2); // type of this item is: OtherObject
```

Hope this helps. Play with it yourself: https://try.haxe.org/#979E1

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.